# subfloat with array?

Tags: subfloats, arrays

the following code produces an error:

> missing $ inserted. 1.109 \end{array}

any suggestions on what I am missing:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My caption goes in here.}
\centering
\subfloat[Subfloat 01]
{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{../PNG/Figure_1.png}}
\subfloat[Subfloat 02]
{\[ \begin{array}{ccc}
$text$ & $text$ & $text$\\
$text$ & $text$ & $text$
\end{array}\]}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use display style math directly in this instance. Rather use `$\begin{array}...\end{array}$`. Here's a complete minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{My caption goes in here.}
\centering
\subfloat[Subfloat 01]
{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{../PNG/Figure_1.png}}
\subfloat[Subfloat 02]
{$\begin{array}{ccc}
text & text & text\\
text & text & text
\end{array}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In order to use display style math - which doesn't seem necessary in your example - you need to provide some fixed width for the float in the form of a `minipage`, say.

The `demo` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is just to make this example compile, since the image `Figure_1.png` is not available.

Comment: your solution worked. i understand now the issue and the solution.