# `missing $ inserted` Error when not putting $ before and after array environment

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, arrays

Considering [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59799/subfloat-with-array) answer I added `$` before and after the array, i. e. before `\begin{array}` and after `\end{array}` in the following code. Then the former `missing $ inserted` Error was gone.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    $\begin{array}{cc}
    z_{ij} = 1      &       \quad \text{if } i, j \in C    \\
    z_{ij} = 0      &       \quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, why is that necessary? I thought the array environment switches LaTex to math mode itself.

Comment: No, it does not change to math mode. It must be used inside a math mode. I suggest you to use `case` (if you need left brace) or `align*` environment to do your cases.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: if ever you find yourself using `\begin{center}$` then you should probably change it to being a display math environment `\[` or here a `cases` from `amsmath`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the `array` environment does *not* automatically switch into math mode; math
needs to be applied explicitly.

a better approach than embedding it in a `center` environment is to put it into
a math display environment; either `equation*` or `\[ ... \]` will suffice.

also, the `\text{...}` string in the first line would be better if it includes
the in-line math expression at the end.

finally, the right-hand column of the array is better left-aligned.

making all these changes, here's a recommended alternative.

```
\[
 \begin{array}{cl}
  z_{ij} = 1      &       \quad \text{if $ i, j \in C $}  \\
  z_{ij} = 0      &       \quad \text{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\]
```

For completeness, here's @DavidCarlisle's suggestion:

```
\[
z_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } i, j \in C   \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
```